# Global keyboard hook in C using DLL doesn't work

Tags: c, hook, keyboard-hook

I tried to do global keyboard hooking in C and got in trouble.

My purpose is that when I type `F2` key or `Ctrl` key, some lines will be printed to check whether it works or not, and if I press the `q` key, it will stop hooking.

To test the whole code, I've used `printf` in some parts.

I have no idea how to figure out this problem, but really want to solve it.

**.cpp code:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"

#define DEF_HOOKSTART  "HookStart"
#define DEF_HOOKSTOP  "HookStop"

typedef void(*PFN_HOOKSTART)();
typedef void(*PFN_HOOKSTOP)();

void main() {
    HMODULE hDll = NULL;
    PFN_HOOKSTART HookStart = NULL;
    PFN_HOOKSTOP HookStop = NULL;
    char ch = 0;

    // load Dll
    hDll = LoadLibrary(L"HookTest.dll");
    if (hDll == NULL) {
        printf("load fail \n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("load success \n");
    }

    HookStart = (PFN_HOOKSTART)GetProcAddress(hDll, DEF_HOOKSTART);
    HookStop = (PFN_HOOKSTOP)GetProcAddress(hDll, DEF_HOOKSTOP);

    HookStart();

    printf("press 'q' to quit!\n");

    // if user push 'q' key, HookStop 
    while (1) {
        if (_getch() == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        printf("Test Typing  \n");
    }

    HookStop();

    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

**.dll code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma data_seg(".kbdata")
HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;
HWND g_hWnd = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.kbdata,RWS")

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstance = hinstDLL;
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" {
    LRESULT __declspec(dllexport) CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        printf("Test 1 --- KeyboardProc sucess \n");
        if (nCode >= 0) {
            printf("Test 2 --- \n");
            if (wParam == VK_F2) {
                printf("F2 Key Typed ");
            }
            else if (wParam == VK_CONTROL) {
                printf("Ctrl Key Typed ");
            }
            else {
                printf("Other Key Typed");
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HookStart() {

    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, g_hInstance, 0);
    printf("Test 3 --- HookStart Call \n");
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HookStop() {
    printf("Test 4 --- HookStop Call \n");
    if (g_hHook) {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        g_hHook = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you say what doesn't work. I don't really want to have to reboot in Windows, compile this code, and run it in order to see what's wrong.

Comment: A WH_KEYBOARD hook is pretty difficult to implement correctly, it requires injecting a DLL into all running processes.  First glaring mistake is that it does not do anything to inject both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.  Second mistake is what it does in the hook callback, the odds that you can see printf() output are quite low on a GUI operating system.  Detecting F2 and CTRL is simple, use either WH_KEYBOARD_LL or RegisterHotKey().